# Should I test my China-targeted website with "360 Secure Browser" (browser in China)?

Tags: cross-browser

Developing a website aiming to the Chinese market, I am wondering whether I should do compatibility tests with the [360 secure browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360_Secure_Browser), which is based on the Trident layout engine (like Internet Explorer).

Any developer experienced in designing websites for China? Did you test on this browser? Is it really different from IE? What is its market share in mainland China?

Comment: You can download it for free.  If the market-share is greater than zero, why wouldn't you test it?  Presumably you test on IE, Firefox, Opera and Chrome when targeting Western audiences.  It costs nothing except for some time to add one more browser to your testing.

Comment: I can't imagine that it's "based on ... Trident" - presumably they just embed the IE browser control and develop a browser around it. I could only imagine that Javascript and ActiveX are off by default, so go fire up IE and turn off JS/AX and you probably have "360 Secure Internet Explorer"

Comment: @DavidO: Multiply by use cases and OS versions, and testing ends up costing a lot, you need to think carefully about what browsers you want to support. @todda.speot.is: Thanks for your answer.